# Matlab - copying a graph (plot) from function to UIAxes in AppDesigner

Tags: matlab

I created a graph in my function:

```
P = plot( graph(names,names),'LineStyle','none','Marker','x','MarkerSize',8,'NodeColor','red','XData',xi,'YData',yi); 
highlight(P,n,'NodeColor','green');
```

How to save/copy this graph and put it in just created UIAxes in App Designer (using callbackf button)?
Or how to plot the same graph directly from App Designer?
Using this button is also called the function where the graph is created.

Thank you all for your guidance and help.

I tried:

plotData = plot(  graph(names,names),'LineStyle','none','Marker','x','MarkerSize',8,'NodeColor','red','XData',xi,'YData',yi);

and then in UIAxes:

plot( app.UIAxesTeziste,P) or plot(app.UIAxesTeziste, plotData.XData, plotData.YDate). For the second try a data were visible but in different way (I would like to have that graph visualized in same way).